# What are the quiz questions in Monsters University?

Tags: pixar, monsters-university

In Monsters University (near the beginning) we are quickly shown an image of a test or quiz taken by Sulley. In the low quality version I watched, I can make out comments like "Zombie Sharks!?"

Are the actual test questions on the quiz readable, and if yes, what are they?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Anatomy of Scare

101

Name J. Sullivan [Graded "C-"]

Multiple Choice

1. Child Toxicity may cause major damage to various organs which can lead to the lethality of the entire body.  Name this syndrome.
   a. Acute Dermal Exposure:  measured in mg/kg of body weight
   b. Hazardous Aspiration
   c. Physical Toxicant Exposure
   [C is selected, but A is correct]
2. When confronted with an adolescent human new dangers arise within the attainment of Scream Energy.  What is a Scarers best response to the above situation?
   a. Continue scaring until adolescent screams
   b. Exit the room and look for other children
   c. Abandon scare and return to Scare floor
   [C is selected, and correct]
3. All scare techniques are based on the various primal fears of humans.  What is the basis of the Zombie Slouch?
   a. Fear of the living dead
   b. Lion attacks
   c. Sharks
   [C is selected, but A is correct.  Teachers note: "Really?  Zombie Sharks?!"]
4. A child that is afraid of thunder but not lightning will respond to a scare tailored towards tonitrophobia.  What scare technique should be used on a child afraid of Thunder and Clowns?
   a. Cobra Hiss combined with Cyclops Wink
   b. Seasonal Creep and Crawl
   c. Oleaginous Roar with a Howling Sad Face
   [A is selected, C is correct.  Teacher's note: "Do you even own the book?!"]
5. True or False.  Human toxicity is treatable:
   [X]  True
   [ ]  False
   [True is selected and correct]
6. If a combination of scares fails to produce the desired level of scream from a child a Scarer should?
   a. Trust in the fundamentals of Scaring
   b. Roar as loudly as possible
   c. Note the childs response and research scare techniques
   [B is selected, but C is correct]

Comment: The detail of "Human toxicity is treatable: True" is nice. The monster government put some thought into explaining why no-one you've met or heard of has ever actually died of human toxicity.

Comment: @Chessanator Does monsters university finally explain why the gov't implemented the human toxicity plan?

Comment: How does 2 out of 6 correct answers result in a C-?  That's a pretty generous grading curve there.  1/3rd of the answers correct should result in a solid F.  I'd say maybe there were more pages, but seeing the picture on Valorum's answer, it's pretty clearly just the one.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman 0 correct obviously equals F-. So From Sully's grade we can deduce that 1 correct equals a D-, 2 correct equals C- (Sully's grade), 3 and 4 correct would be a B-, and A-, respectively (one full letter grade per question answered). That leaves 5 and 6 correct answers for an "A" and "A+" grade.

Answer (score 26):

The question that provoked his teacher's response was

> "*All scare techniques are based on the various primal fears of humans. What is the basis of the Zombie Slouch?*"

To which Sully has ticked "*Sharks*" rather than the correct answer (e.g. "*Fear of the living dead*")

[image]